# How to save image using return Uri?

Tags: java, android, imageuri

I am using an image background remover library from GitHub.
My image is not being saved in storage after done with removing background.

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CutOut.CUTOUT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Uri imageUri = CutOut.getUri(data);
                // Save the image using the returned Uri here
                //what code to add here so i can save my image
                how to save image using Retun Uri
                Intent intent1=new Intent(BackgroundRemover.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case CutOut.CUTOUT_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE:
                Exception ex = CutOut.getError(data);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("User cancelled the CutOut screen");
                Intent intent2=new Intent(BackgroundRemover.this,AdvanceFeatures.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }
}
```

How to save image using return Uri?

Comment: `my image is not being saved in storage after done with removing background` What kind of image? Where does it suddenly come from? What does it have to do with removing a backgroud? A background of what?

Comment: You can create a file object from your uri and save it in storage. File temp = new File(uri), save and read this file again, after you only need to knowledge working with storage in android.

Comment: Please do not repost your problem within three hours. And certainly not without even answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

A practical way to save an image by URI is by writing the code below :

1 - Get the Uri of the image using `CutOut.getUri(data)`.

2- `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap` to get a Bitmap object

3- `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageUri)` to get an `OutputStream` object to write the image data to the Uri.

4 - `bitmap.compress` to compress the image data and write it to the OutputStream.

5 - case `Activity.RESULT_OK:` (block of your) `onActivityResult` method.

```
    Uri imageUri = CutOut.getUri(data);
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
    String displayName = "my_image.png"; // Set the name of the image file here
    OutputStream fos = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + displayName));
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer means a lot but just elaborate a little where i have to use displayName???

Comment: and what about onActivityResult method idk kindly help me

Comment: this did not give me any error but still image is not saved

Comment: `DisplayName` variable is storing just the name of the file as a String, you can use it to make an URI to specify where to save the image. check the code i updated it ;)

Comment: `CutOut` library saves the image file in the application's cache directory, You can use `getCacheDir()` method to get the path to the cache directory. You can also specify a custom directory to save the file. For example, you can save the file in the external storage directory by using `getExternalFilesDir()` method. You can find more details on the official documentation

Comment: Thank you so much its working now..... keep on helping new programmers

Comment: only 1 confusion yes its saving image now but with blackish background in folder its showing white but when i oepn that image saved afyer removing background showing black background ???

Comment: Maybe you have a PNG image without a background so thats why you have different colors it depends with which program your reading the picture, it is not a  problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the byte array from URI and convert the byte array to a file using output and input stream.

Get Bytearray from URI

```
result?.data?.data?.let {
                val byteArray = contentResolver.openInputStream(it)?.readBytes() }
```

Get the file information from URI

```
    /*
 * Get the file's content URI from the incoming Intent,
 * then query the server app to get the file's display name
 * and size.
 */
returnIntent.data?.let { returnUri ->
    contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
}?.use { cursor ->
    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     * and display it.
     */
    val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
    val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
    cursor.moveToFirst()
    val fileName = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
    val fileSize = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex).toString()
}
```

Write file from byte array

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(byteArray);
fos.close();
```